# navigating to a different page within the application using angular js

Tags: angularjs, ng-view

This question might sound very generic to some of you but as a newbie i am having trouble in this. Its evident to use ng-view within the home page in order to display other html files within the page but how should i redirect to a new page present in the web app. I mean how to route to completely different web page in a multipage web application.

Answer (score 2):

**Import AngularJs-Route File**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script>
```

**Then you must add the `ngRoute` as a dependency in the application module:**

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
```

**Use the `$routeProvider` to configure different routes in your application:**

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
  .when("/", {
    templateUrl : "main.htm"
  })
  .when("/red", {
    templateUrl : "red.htm"
  })
  .when("/green", {
    templateUrl : "green.htm"
  })
  .when("/blue", {
    templateUrl : "blue.htm"
  });
});
```

**STructure Your HTML**

```
<body ng-app="myApp">

<p><a href="#/">Home</a></p>
<a href="#red">Red</a>
<a href="#green">Green</a>
<a href="#blue">Blue</a>

<div ng-view></div>
</body>
```

For nested views you can use https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

Follow https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-&-Nested-Views for reference

Comment: i want the page to redirect to another page and not to include html in the ng-view, when i click on hyperlinks red green or blue

Comment: @jayendrabhatt you mean to a different domain?

Comment: no, i mean in "green.htm", can i write ng-view in green.htm and not in the html template file which contain the hyperlinks.

Comment: No you cannot, Just use [https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) for that. It allows using nested views.

Answer (score 0):

Try searching angular ui-roter how its works and its mechanism . Since angular is a single page application your app needs to be on one base template then expand from their.  From base template route in different page but  if you want to route to different application use normal hyper link or ui-serf . Go though  [u-router](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_routing.asp) basic. Also  look into [ui-serf](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/0.3.1/index.html#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-sref) .